# Calling the function in Controller throws not defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am new to Angular Java scripting and I am trying to call a function and use the returned value in a Controller like below

```
    $scope.findprojectBarcode = function (p) {
        var prjBarCode = "";
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < $rootScope.projectList.value.length; i++) {
            if ($rootScope.projectList.value[i].Name === p) {
                console.log($rootScope.projectList.value[i].Name);
                return $rootScope.projectList.value[i].Barcode;
            }
        }
        return prjBarCode;
    };

   $scope.postRequest = function () {
        var prjCode = findprojectBarcode($scope.request.projectSelectedBarcode);
        var data = {
            "PROJECT@odata.bind": ["/PROJECT('" + prjCode + "')"]
        };
```

But when try to debug it throws error like `findprojectBarcode is not defined`. I am not sure if I am missing something here.

The html Code is

```
        <div hidden id="projectSelected">
            <label style="font-size: medium">Project *</label>
            <select name="projectSelected" id="projectSelectedId" class="form-control" ng-model="request.projectSelectedBarcode" required>
              <option ng-repeat="prj in projectList" value="{{prj.Name}}">{{ prj.Name }}</option>
            </select>
            <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="getServiceReuqestForm.projectSelected.$error"
                 ng-if="getServiceReuqestForm.projectSelected.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: post your HTML code

Comment: @Sajeetharan Added the HTML Code as well. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var prjCode = $scope.findprojectBarcode($scope.request.projectSelectedBarcode);
```

Comment: Still getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at m.$scope.findprojectBarcode`

Comment: it seems your   $rootScope.projectList is empty or null. add a null check. or check why values are missing

Comment: `projectList` has data. I can see them in the dropdown. Trying to use them in the function but it breaks

Comment: i guess you need $rootScope.projectList.length instead of $rootScope.projectList.value.length

Comment: am sure you are doing something basically wrong. anyway the above solution will make your function to get invoked. just debug and se what you are missing